# What does IDLE state denotes in a row of pg_stat_activity?

Tags: postgresql

Can someone resolve my below doubts about `pg_stat_activity` in terms of postgres 9.5?

1. Can some let me know what does the `state` `IDLE` denotes in the row of `pg_stat_activity`? Is it like it checks all the open connections to postgres and if the connection is not executing any query then `IDLE` denotes the last query executed by the connection?
2. In the output of `select * from pg_stat_activity` I am seeing rows with `state` `IDLE` and the `query_start_date` more than 2 days old? What does this signify ? Should I be worried about this?
3. Can someone let me know how pg_stat_activity is populated? If I am executing a query like `Select * from pg_stat_activity` does it produce the details from some snapshot maintained by postgres or it checks the current connections open in postgres to provide the details?

Comment: re 1): https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This has been answered in postgres [mailing list](https://postgrespro.com/list/id/CAC6ry0LFHv+eMjpde_3jqfSnG9hg2O6s=9VTwLh2jiYydXSqGg@mail.gmail.com)

> Each row in pg_stat_activity represents an established connection to
>   the server from a client. "idle" means the client is not currently
>   executing a query nor in a transaction.
>
> If query_start_date is 2 days old, that just means the last query to
>   be executed on that connection was two days ago.
>
> Not really a reason for worry, unless you have so many connections
>   open that it's consuming more RAM than you can afford. It's generally
>   desirable for a connection pool to have a few idle connections so
>   queries don't suffer the latency of establishing a new connection.